# Where in i add slice to the final javascript string?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom

```
<body>
   
    <div id="dice0" class="dice">0</div>
    <div id="dice1" class="dice">0</div>
    <button onclick ="rollDice()">Roll a Pair of Dice</button>
    <br>
    <button onclick ="rollDice1000()"> Roll 1000 Times</button>
    <br>
    <div id="result"class="current"></div>
    
    <div id="list" class="list"></div>
    <script src="code.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
let results = [null, null, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];

function rollDice(){
    let dice0 = document.getElementById("dice0");
    let dice1 = document.getElementById("dice1");
    let result = document.getElementById("result");
    let list = document.getElementById("list");
    let d0= Math.floor(Math.random()*6)+1;
    let d1= Math.floor(Math.random()*6)+1;
    let total = d0+d1;
    dice0.innerHTML = d0;
    dice1.innerHTML = d1;
    result.innerHTML = "You rolled "+total+"."
    results[total]+=1;
   
    list.innerHTML = results.map((val, index)=> `You have rolled ${index}: ${val} times`).join('<br/>');

}
```

The code above is a simple javascript dice game that tracks the number of times a result is given.
*the results should be between 2 and 12*
What you will see is:
You have rolled 0: null times
You have rolled 1: null times

The final string spits out 2 null variables that should not be listed; because they can not be rolled (0 and 1)**I do not want to changed the array**. **Where and how can I add a ".slice()" to remove them from the output?** or is there a better way to do it with *javascript?* 
Subsequently, is there a way to break up the list? That I may organize the output with CSS?
for example; 

[You have rolled 2: 7 times.]    [You have rolled 3: 2 times.]    [You have rolled 4: 5 times.] [and so on] 
*assume the brackets are styled elements*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a ternary operator to only add `${val} times` to the output if `val` is not `null`:

```js
let results = [null, null, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];

function rollDice() {
  let dice0 = document.getElementById("dice0");
  let dice1 = document.getElementById("dice1");
  let result = document.getElementById("result");
  let list = document.getElementById("list");
  let d0 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
  let d1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
  let total = d0 + d1;
  dice0.innerHTML = d0;
  dice1.innerHTML = d1;
  result.innerHTML = "You rolled " + total + "."
  results[total] += 1;

  list.innerHTML = results.map((val, index) => val != null ? `You have rolled ${index} ${val} times` : null).join('<br/>');

}
```

```html
<body>

  <div id="dice0" class="dice">0</div>
  <div id="dice1" class="dice">0</div>
  <button onclick="rollDice()">Roll a Pair of Dice</button>
  <br>
  <button onclick="rollDice1000()"> Roll 1000 Times</button>
  <br>
  <div id="result" class="current"></div>

  <div id="list" class="list"></div>
  <script src="code.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

If you want to style each, you can wrap them in a `div`:

```js
let results = [null, null, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];

function rollDice() {
  let dice0 = document.getElementById("dice0");
  let dice1 = document.getElementById("dice1");
  let result = document.getElementById("result");
  let list = document.getElementById("list");
  let d0 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
  let d1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
  let total = d0 + d1;
  dice0.innerHTML = d0;
  dice1.innerHTML = d1;
  result.innerHTML = "You rolled " + total + "."
  results[total] += 1;

  list.innerHTML = results.map((val, index) => val != null ? `<div class="item">You have rolled ${index} ${val} times</div>` : null).join('<br/>');

}
```

```css
.item {
  padding: 10px;
  background: lightgrey;
  margin: 10px;
}

#list {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div id="dice0" class="dice">0</div>
  <div id="dice1" class="dice">0</div>
  <button onclick="rollDice()">Roll a Pair of Dice</button>
  <br>
  <button onclick="rollDice1000()"> Roll 1000 Times</button>
  <br>
  <div id="result" class="current"></div>

  <div id="list" class="list"></div>
  <script src="code.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You have rolled 0
You have rolled 1
 
Pop up as results still, between the 2 answers lies the solution!

Comment: @HelpWantedSign I've updated my answer. It should work now.

Answer (score 0):

You can skip adding an entry if there's no value:

```
list.innerHTML = results.map((val, index)=> {
 if(val && val > 0){
  return `You have rolled ${index}: ${val} times`;
 }
 return null;
});
```

Additionally, if you want more control with css, you could wrap each entry in a `div` and then style them all according to your desires.

```
 list.innerHTML = results.map((val, index)=> {
  if(val && val > 0){
   return `<div class="myClass">You have rolled ${index}: ${val} times</div>`;
  }
  return '';
 });
```

Comment: for some reason{when i added this code} I now have several commas on the page,  they show up between each dice roll div on the live server! tricky little buggers, I have no idea how they got there!